# Adding GN and MOH Areas as Extensions to FHIR Patient Resource for Sri Lanka

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm interested in understanding how the FHIR framework can be adapted to represent specific geographical administrative boundaries in Sri Lanka, namely the GN (Grama Niladhari) area and the MOH (Medical Officer of Health) area.

The GN area represents the most granular geographical administrative boundary in Sri Lanka.
Several GN areas come together to form an MOH area.
Every patient in Sri Lanka is associated with both a GN area and an MOH area.
Given the importance of these areas, I'm considering the possibility of adding them as extensions directly to the Patient resource in FHIR. This would allow for capturing this crucial information at the patient level without embedding it within the Address resource.

Has anyone had experience or seen implementations where similar geographical or administrative attributes were added directly to the Patient resource using FHIR extensions? Are there best practices or considerations to be aware of when taking this approach?

Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly map one of these to the 'district' element if either of these are a 'standard' part of the address.  Otherwise, yes, extensions would be the best solution.  Best practice would be to ideally coordinate the definition of the extension nationally so that all implementations in the country use the same extension for the same purpose.  Think about whether this is something that should be coded vs. free text.